# Mongo count really slow when there are millions of records

Tags: mongodb

```
//FAST
db.datasources.find().count()
12036788

//SLOW    
db.datasources.find({nid:19882}).count()
10161684
```

Index on nid

Any way to make the second query faster? (It is taking about 8 seconds)

Comment: Even though you've got an index on nid, it might not be resident in memory.  What happens if you run the query a second time, is it any faster?

Comment: How long is the first query taking? Are you sure there are no other operations running on the server?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Count queries, indexed or otherwise, are slow due to the fact that MongoDB still has to do a full b-tree walk to find the appropriate number of documents that match your criteria. The reason for this is that the MongoDB b-tree structure is not "counted" meaning each node does not store information about the number of elements in the node/subtree.

The issue is reported here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752 and there is currently no workaround to improve performance other than manually maintaining a counter for that collection which obviously comes with a few downsides.

Also, note that the db.col.count() version (so no criteria) can take a big shortcut and doesn't actually perform a query hence its speed. That said it does not always report the same value as a count query that should return all elements (it won't be in shared environments with high write throughput for example). Up for debate whether or not that's a bug. I think it is.

Note that in 2.3+ a significant optimization was introduced that should (and does) improve the performance of counts on indexed fields. See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7745

Comment: I wonder how to use for examle pagination with mongodb, if count is so slow.

Comment: Pagination is a more complex problem than it might seem when you work with big data. For example, skip(N) is an o(N) operation so you can't really make pagination based on skip(pageIndex * pageSize).limit(pageSize) nor can you determine the total page count with a count(). You can but it will become slower as data size increases which is a bad pattern. There are solutions mind you, they're just more complicated than that. All that said count() should be faster than they are and MongoDB should (at least optionally) use counted b-trees in my opinion.

Comment: I had no luck searching for the pagination on big data that does not utilize skip and limit. If anyone has an example it would be great to share

Comment: @vodich The solutions are generally context specific. it's hard to suggest a solution to you without some sort of context.

Comment: also having same problem of pagination large collections 1M+ docs. Aggregation works, but `count(query)` just times out.

Answer (score 31):

As @Remon said, count() has to scan all the documents matching the query/filter. It is O(n) where n is the number of documents that will match the index, or the number of documents in the collection if the field is not indexed.

In such cases, you typically want to revisit your requirement.  Do you really need a precise number for the result 10161684? If the precision is important, you should keep a separate counter for the particular query.

But in most cases, precision is not important. It's one of the two:

- You don't care whether it's 10 million or 10.2 million, but the order of magnitude is important, i.e., you care about whether it's 8 million or 10 million.
- You only care about the precise number if it's a small one. I.e., you're interested to know that there are 44 results or 72. But once it goes beyond, say, 1000, you can just say 'More than 1000 objects' found to the user.

In my apps, I found that the second option is what I want. So, I limit the count() query as well, so that the counting stops when it reaches a limit. Like so:

```
db.datasources.find({nid: 19882}).limit(1000).count(true)
```

To the user, I display '1000 *or more* results found' if the count is 1000, otherwise, I display the exact number.

As for the first option ... I haven't thought of a neat solution yet.

Comment: what does `.count(true)` do here?

Comment: count() returns the number of documents matched. count() takes an argument `applySkipLimit` which affects whether the count is on the skipped and limited set, or the entire set (only filtered). If you pass true, it will limit the counting to 1000. If you pass false, it will go through all the matched documents to get the count -- this is going to be slow, and not what you want.

Answer (score -6):

It has to look through every field of every document for the second.  You could index `nid` to make the count faster.