# Can I improve MongoDB aggregate performance?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm trying to port a solution that currently exists in MS SQL 2005 to MongoDB - the currenty schema is structured, but we're hoping to add a new level of data that while not schema-less is more variant in structure so noSQL seemed a way to go.

The main use of the data is analytical and we run a lot of aggregations on the data. However I am struggling with performance of aggregate queries in MongoDB and I'm not sure where the problem lies - it could be my expectations, my limited knowledge of MongDB ( i'm just learning) or it might be that MongoDB is not the right tool for the job.

I've read the MongoDb manual on collections, indexes, aggregations.  There are some simple [aggregation examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) and as part of my learning I decided to use follow these.

However, at the first attempt (using the first example) I found that performance was slower than perhaps I expected, and certainly slower than what I can achieve with MS SQL. My Guess is that I'm doing something wrong but I don't really know what and my intuition has failed me - such that I'm asking this question.

**The Test**
I want to count how many entities match a simple 'starting with' query on a single field.

This matches a basic `select count() from where` pattern in SQL and using the comparison example from the MongoDB site.

**The Data**

The raw data has 21^6 rows. In MongoDB I have this has a single collection with no blanks, so 21^6 documents with approx 17-40 fields (avg 28).

It has single index - I chose this as it is a common field in our analytics. I let Mongo name it.

```js
{
    "n4" : 1
}
```

The index is about 2Gb in size, so - if I understand correctly - should be plenty of room in memory for it.

In MSSQL this is a single table with 40 columns. in MS SQL the table has the following index

```sql
USE [v3_newDev]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [n4]    Script Date: 05/30/2014 13:34:19 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [n4] ON [dbo].[beta_3_dev_POST_coded] 
(
    [n4] ASC,
    [pn4] ASC,
    [ypCat Code] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [SIC div],
[SIC 2]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A little more complex, but its a covering index designed for some queries that ultimately I'd like to reproduce on MongoDB.

**The machine**
Dual Xeon 5050 quad core, 24Gb ram, slow disks but lots of them and well partitioned. In the MS-SQL and in Mongo the various parts get their own spindle. I'm the sole user of this development environment.

**What I did**

First test in mongoDB, is a replication of simple count/where query.

```js
db.main.find({n4:/^UKN/}).count()
```

returns n = 2306913 in 25.714 sec.

Checking with PerfMon shows that no disk activity is happening, so I guessing this is all happening in memory, but then it seems slow.

so, I look at the explain just to make sure....

```js
db.main.find({n4:/^UKN/}).explain()
```

the results:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor n4_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2306913,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2306913,
    "nscanned" : 2306914,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2306913,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2306914,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 18022,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 22255,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "n4" : [ 
            [ 
                "UKN", 
                "UKO"
            ], 
            [ 
                /^UKN/, 
                /^UKN/
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "rack01:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "FETCH",
        "works" : 2306914,
        "yields" : 18022,
        "unyields" : 18022,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2306913,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "forcedFetches" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                "works" : 2306913,
                "yields" : 18022,
                "unyields" : 18022,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2306913,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : "{ n4: 1.0 }",
                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['n4']: [\"UKN\", \"UKO\"), [/^UKN/, /^UKN/]",
                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 2306914,
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Everything seems OK to me there, it's using the BTreeCursor for an indexscan. But I'm trying to make it faster.

Checking against the manual I noticed that `indexOnly`, which is set to `false`, is unnecessary in this scenario, so try with the method

```js
._addSpecial( "$returnKey", true )
```

From reading the manual and other stuff on the web this method tells the query planner to use only the n4 field which is available in the index

This is indeed quicker...

```js
db.main.find({n4:/^UKN/})._addSpecial( "$returnKey", true ).explain().n
```

returns n = 2306913 in  9.896sec.

An improvement but still an order of magnitude slower than I'd like and what I can achive with MS SQL.

My next step is to go back to the `.count()` method with `_addSpecial()` method, although this is fruitless as this yields the longest times of all

returns n = 2306913 in  129.575sec. (although in subsequent tests its around 23/25 secs.)

How can I improve these query times for MongoDB? Is the something more I can do with indexing, or a better query pattern?

In MS SQL 2005, using the following simple query

SELECT COUNT(*) as n
    FROM v3_newDev..beta_3_dev_POST_coded
    WHERE n4 LIKE 'UKN%'`

the query returns n = 2306913 in < 1 sec.

Given what I written here, what can I do with MongoDB to improve the performance of this basic query?

Comment: It is good to note that the return of the explain which you would plan to use alternatively is only an approximation, it is also a counter, it is not unique. That might be why MS SQL is a lot faster

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778420/mongo-count-really-slow-when-there-are-millions-of-records

Comment: Much more man-hours were invested in tuning and improving MSSQL. And mongodb still has goddamned db-level write locks. Don't overestimate its capabilities :)